# Training multi-variate LSTM model with sample observations with differenet mean values

Tags: time-series, regression, lstm

I am developing an LSTM model to predict the force-deformation response for wind turbine blades. I have generated the training data from a high-fidelity model for wind speeds ranging from 3m/s to 25m/s. Naturally, the input feature has varying mean values, and so does the output. I can normalize the input features while training the LSTM model by including the `layerNormalization` functionality in Matlab but this won't allow me to normalize the output time history. Due to this, the predicted output has a constant mean. How do I get around this?